# Wrong dependency version number showing in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-appcompat

In my android project dependencies are added like this

[image]

the androidxappcompat_version version defined in root project is 1.4.1. One of the third party library uses 1.0.0 version that I figured out from transverse dependencies tree.

I have already cleared/deleted cache, build folders.

I have tried this as well:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { details ->
            if ('androidx.appcompat' == details.requested.group) {
                details.useVersion "1.4.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Still it is picking up wrong dependency version.

Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this. Why :app gradle showing 1.0.0 instead of 1.4.1.

Comment: Does `./gradlew dependencies` also show `1.0.0` instead of `1.4.1` ?